# Java Pig Latin Converter is spitting out an extra word

Tags: java, apache-pig, converters, latin

I'm working on a project for my Programming Applications course with WGU. I've decided to adapt a python-based pig latin converter from the previous course. I've almost got it done, but when I run the program, I get an extra word. For example, if I enter Latin, it prints atinLay, then on the next line, prints inLatay.

[image]

I'm not sure which part of the code is causing this. I know it should be a simple fix but I just can't find it. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class PigConverter
{ 
public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
Scanner anscay = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a word:"); 
String word = anscay.nextLine(); 
System.out.println("This word, in pig latin, would be:");

String pigConvert;
 for (int i=0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
       if(word.charAt(i)=='a' || word.charAt(i)=='e' || word.charAt(i)=='i' ||
           word.charAt(i)=='o' || word.charAt(i)=='u') 
            {
              String second = word.substring(0,i);
              String first = word.substring(i,word.length());
              System.out.println(first+second+"ay");    
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so what should be the expected outcome for latin?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski *Pig Latin. It's basically just English, where the first letter is moved to the end, and "ay" is added if it was a consonant.

Comment: You should put program results inline, because every link is eventually a dead link. What have you tried? What were the results? Since you are getting extra results, you will have to concentrate on the conditions of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your loop is finding BOTH vowels in the word, so it/s doing the output twice. I think that your loop should break once you find the first vowel.